# Assuming a constant area, what shape can take the most forces?

Tags: forces

Assuming that I have a thin surface with constant area.

[image]

I need to use it to build it into the strongest force resistant element in $z$ direction from top: a shape that can withstand the biggest force.

Here are some of the characteristics of my plate area:

1. The force is assumed to be applicable uniformly across the surface. In other words, the stress ( *force per unit area*) $\vec q(x,y)=q\hat z$, where $q$ is a constant
2. There is no hole across the surface
3. The $xy$ boundary of the surface is fixed for all of the translational and rotational coordinates ${x,y,z, \theta_x, \theta_y, \theta_z}$.
4. The thickness ( $h$) of the surface is a small constant, compare to the cross sectional dimension.
5. The ratio $a/b$ are fixed. So that leaves only the middle parts of the plat that can be flexed.
6. I can bend it like a membrane into any shape I want to, as long as each point on the surface is differentiable and continuous.

What would the shape of my "force resistant element" be? Is it a membrane, or just plain flat surface? Why?

Comment: It all depends on which direction the force is applied relative to the shape. Without further details in the question it is hard to answer exactly. Are you talking about a table, or trampoline, a beam, a column, or some other general geometry.

Comment: @ja72, question edited. Is it better now?

Comment: Is the downwards force applied evenly over the whole surface or could it be concentrated at a single point?

Comment: @Amphibio , its applicable evenly

Comment: Is the force always in z-direction or perpendicular to the surface? In what way is the force uniform? Also, an infinitely thin membrane cannot have any strength, as stress in a material generally is a volume force, especially if you want to consider non-planar shapes

Comment: Can the shape have holes? If so create a thin ring near the supports and you will have a strong design. In general the closer you move the applied loads to the boundary conditions the stronger the design.

Comment: You can use [`this`](http://www.efunda.com/formulae/solid_mechanics/plates/calculators/CCCC_PUniform.cfm) calculator.

Comment: @planetmaker, see the updated question, is it now answerable?

Comment: @ja72, see the updated question, is it now answerable?

Comment: What is the difference between a membrane or a flat surface? Also what is stopping you from making $a$ extremely large and $b$ small?

Comment: Try [Engineering.SE] instead.

Comment: Also read reference for flat plates [Flat_Plate_Deflection-Chapter13.pdf](http://files.engineering.com/download.aspx?folder=f1bfc2a4-baaf-4465-89db-ec5f7b0012bd&file=Flat_Plate_Deflection-Chapter13.pdf)

Comment: @ja72 , let's assume that the ratio $a/b$ are actually fixed

Comment: So if $a/b$ is fixed and the area $a b$ is fixed and the thickness $h$ is fixed, what is the question? The dimensions are fixed as it is now. If the area varies make it as small as possible, and if the shape varies make it as long as possible.

Comment: @ja72, the ratio of $a/b$ is fixed, but that doesn't mean that individually, $a$ and $b$ are fixed.

Comment: Yes it does. If $a/b=r$ and $a b=A$ then $$ \begin{align} a & = \sqrt{A r} \\ b &= \sqrt{A/r} \end{align} $$